# Dynamic names when initializing variables in C++

Tags: c++, variables, dynamic, vector

I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically name variables - to be more precise; **Is there a way to initialize variables in for-loops in such a way that every time the loop executes a part of the name changes?** E.g: creating 10 variables with the names row1, row2, row3, row4 [...] row10 - where "row" stays the same but the number at the end changes.

Why I need to know: I'm trying to get my head around two-dimensional vectors and ran into a problem; *every* row of my vector matrix is a vector with the name "row" and it is therefore not possible to check the length of the rows using the `.size` method on them (like with the columns) since they don't have unique names.

```
//Creation of vector
vector <vector <int> > multiVector;    
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //Vector is given 5 rows
        vector <int> rad (7);
        multiVector.push_back(rad); //The newly declared vector is filled with rows
    }

//Vector is printed
    for (int i = 0; i < multiVector.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            cout << multiVector[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

**Thank you for your help!**

Comment: Variable names are a static component of the language. You can not create them dynamically, but you can hack around this by using a `unordered_map<string, value_type>`. Kind of like what dynamic languages do internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the size of the `i`th row by accessing that row and then calling `size` on it:  `multiVector[i].size()`.

And no, you can't dynamically generate variable names. Variable names exist only in source code and at compile-time to assist the programmer and compiler in identifying different variables. They do not exist at run-time, so cannot be generated while the program is running. If you ever think you need variables with increasing numbers after their names, then what you really want is an array.

Comment: I think there are a bunch of cases where dynamic variables come in useful (parsing JSON for example), but they aren't very C++y.

Comment: Oh of course! i do not know why I didn't think of that *facepalm*, but thanks!